# Mysql - how to design indexes for a query with WHERE and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I work with MySQL (MyISAM) DB.

I have a query like this:

```
select c1, c2, c3, MAX(c5) from T where c4=#string_value# group by c1, c2, c3

- c[1-4] are varchar(255)
- c5 is an integer
```

I've tried two indexes:

- "c1_c2_c3_idx" for (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`) - that makes query work 3 times slower
- "c4_idx" for (`c4`) - that makes query work 5 times faster

Maybe there is a way to create even more fast index?

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM?

Answer (score 2):

I see the following index being optimal:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON T (c4, c1, c2, c3, c5);
```

The index begins with `c4`, which appears in the `WHERE` clause, which is the first part of the query execution.  Next, we add `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, to cover the `GROUP BY` clause.  After this, we add `c5`, which will make it much faster for MySQL to find `MAX(c5)`.

Note that the above index can be said to *cover* the entire query, because MySQL can use the index alone to satisfy the entire query plan, without needing to seek back to the clustered index (table).

Answer (score 1):

The best index should bd based on where condition  ...

```
 create index  idx1 on T ( c4)
```

for avoid the access to data table and use only info contained  in index you can also try using a redundant index  adding the column involved in others clauses

```
create index  idx1 on T ( c4, c1,c2,c3,c5)
```

leaving the where column left most